# GameKitHelper: Displaying Game Center leaderboards

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gamekit

I am using GameKitHelper for my Cocos2d game. At some point, I will want to display the leaderboards, so I do this:

```
[[GameKitHelper sharedGameKitHelper] showLeaderboard];
```

But nothing happens. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show gameKit helper? Its wrong..

it should be this:

```
- (void) showLeaderboard
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
    }
}
```

reference at this link: [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW13)

The code for cocos2d..

```
UIViewController* _tmpView = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    GKLeaderboardViewController* gclb = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
gclb.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:_tmpView.view]; 
    [_tmpView presentModalViewController:gclb animated:NO];
```

Comment: Where do I put that code? Because in my Cocos2d scene, self doesn't have a presentModalViewController method.

Comment: Well, this is very interesting: My game is landscape mode, and when I run that code, the simulator gets portrait mode, so I can tell something happened. BUT no leaderboard appears at all. The game continues running like normal... why is that? And thank you very much for the help so far! Some info: My application is already linked to the iTunes thing. My user is already authenticated.

Comment: NEVERMIND! Managed to fix it. Thank you very much ;D!

Comment: @xuanweng: GameKitHelper is a wrapper class I wrote for my book, Learn Cocos2D: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/